# web browser control not working in windows phone 7.1

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am using a webbrowser control in windows phone 7 application (7.1 OS), but the web browser control is showing the blank white page even I setting it with proper URl :

```
(wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));)
```

My questions are:

1. Does webbrowser control does not work in windows phone 7.1 OS ?
2. Any compatiability issuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. Probably the UriKind you are using is the problem

```
wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```